# Search for string and send mail

Tags: unix

I need help to write a script for the below logic

```
egrep -i '06:00|06:01|06:02' GSEQOPT2015-12-10.log|grep 'Heatbeat'   
2015-12-10 06:00:31,419 INFO  out.GCPRS_ENGINE - >2 Heartbeat  
2015-12-10 06:00:47,747 INFO  in.GXPRTS_ENGINE - <2 Heartbeat
```

If I found  Heartbeat string in my log i need to send a notification mail , how to write script for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep -F "SomeString" "$File"; then
    sendmail user@example.com  < /tmp/email.txt 
fi
```

You can also use different conditions with grep like `-F`, `-q`, `-r` for different purposes. For more check `man grep`

You can add some text in email.txt like:

```
Subject: XYZ
line 1
line 2
```

You can find some more help here for sending mail with linux commands: 
([5 Ways to Send Email From Linux Command Line](http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/))

Comment: please accept the answer if it has resolved your issue or helped you positively. It may be useful to someone else. All the best